# how to return to ajax enviroment after upload a file using iframe

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins

hi im working into a full ajax enviroment page, but i have the need to upload a file into my app, i used an iframe to "display" my form to upload (since i cant upload a file using pure ajax enviroment) but when i try to return to my ajax enviroment i cant get the view that i need, i keep locked "inside" the iframe, any ideas how to get out of the iframe and continue my app processing?
or an alternative to do this using jquery?

thanks a lot Mitzato

edit
im using rails 3 
some html5
and ajax

Answer (score 0):

You could update a div in the parent of the iframe with the response you get in the iframe using the top.document, like:

```
$("#myid", top.document);
```

You would need to include jquery.js in the iframe...

Answer (score 0):

Well the final solution was to create a parent div and in another view create the iframe, then insert my form into my iframe, and finally I add and script in the botton that deletes the div where the iframe is contained that returns me to my ajax environment.